# npm run server error '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Tags: angular, npm, npm-run

I ran into this problem with angular and npm and I'm yet to find a solution for it . The project I'm working is [this angular project from github](https://github.com/angular-university/angular-course/tree/3-services) , this exact code worked for others so the issue is probably from my side .

the command npm run server gives the following error:

> angular-course@0.0.0 server
> ./server.ts
>
> '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
> program or batch file.

The server script in package.json file:

```
"server": "./node_modules/.bin/ts-node -P ./server.tsconfig.json ./server.ts"
```

I ran the npm install command first and all the files and dependencies are succefully installed so I'm not sure what's the problem .

Comment: Are you running this on pc or mac?

Comment: Windows 10 - pc

Comment: maybe you are using old nodejs version?

Comment: my node version is v14.16.0

Comment: update your node, check the path in your system, reinstall the node. And try this too  `npm install -g ts-node`

Comment: already tried `npm install -g ts-node` and it didn't fix the problem , I'm going to update node rn to see if it helps .

Comment: updated node , still the same problem

Comment: Hi Erika, I also came across the exact same issue. Can you please tell me how you resolved this??

Answer (score 1):

This repository seems to be outdated. I had the same problem.
In order to fix the issue, try this command:
`.\node_modules\.bin\ts-node -P .\server.tsconfig.json .\server.ts`

The content of `server.ts` is as follows:

```
import * as express from 'express';
import {Application} from 'express';
import {getAllCourses} from './server/get-courses.route';
import {saveCourse} from './server/save-course.route';


const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app: Application = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.route('/api/courses').get(getAllCourses);

app.route('/api/courses/:id').put(saveCourse);



const httpServer = app.listen(9000, () => {
    console.log('HTTP REST API Server running at http://localhost:' + httpServer.address().port);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with the `/` itself so replace it to something like that `.\\node_modules\\.bin\\ts-node -P ./server.tsconfig.json ./server.ts`

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem is with "/" in the command on windows.
Replace it with "" and it will work like as follows

```
.\node_modules\.bin\ts-node -P .\server.tsconfig.json .\server.ts
```